# Build run's into error and fails in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce, p4v

I am using jenkins for the build but every time i run a build it gives an error and fails?

These are the errors :

> FATAL: hudson/tasks/Mailer$UserProperty
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.tasks.Mailer$UserProperty
>     
> at
>   jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1374)
>     
> at
>   jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1327)
>     
> at
>   jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1080)
>     
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   Caused: 
>  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   hudson/tasks/Mailer$UserProperty  
> at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.changes.P4ChangeRef.getChangeEntry(P4ChangeRef.java:18)
>     
> at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.tasks.CheckoutTask.getChangesFull(CheckoutTask.java:287)
>     
> at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.PerforceScm.calculateChanges(PerforceScm.java:535)
>     
> at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.PerforceScm.checkout(PerforceScm.java:496)
>     
> at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)    
> at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
>     
> at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
>     
> at
>   jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>     
> at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
>     
> at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)  
> at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   
> at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Looks like incompatible Versions of plugin and jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an out-of-date plugin/Jenkins install.

I would recommend updating Jenkins if you're on an older version (I'm currently running 2.121.2).

After Jenkins is updated, try updating all of your plugins as well.

From the main Jenkins page, click "Manage Jenkins" and then "Manage Plugins" or just navigate to: http://yourjenkins.install/pluginManager/.

Scroll to the bottom of the page, click the link "All" near the word Select. Then click the big blue Update button.

This will probably resolve the issue, if not, you've got a bigger issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i am also using jenkins 2.141. Then also i must upgrade it?

Comment: Which version you think might be compatible?

Comment: Your version of jenkins is newer than mine, so you don't have to worry about upgrading Jenkins itself. Skip to the part in my answer when I mention upgrading plugins. That's probably the part that will resolve your issue.

Comment: There are no updates shown in manage plugins section issue is still unresolved! Any other method except the updation ?

Comment: Which plugins are you using on the build that's failing? Are you using any environment variables like this: $BUILD_NUMBER?

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? Facing the same thing with Jenkins 2.235.2 and P4 Plugin 1.10.14 which are both latest I believe

Comment: Hey sorry for so late reply but yeah plugin version was affecting this issue. In Jenkins you always need to take care about the plugin version as sometimes old version works and new ones do not.